# Как выполнить for для фрейма данных к CSV файлам из заданной папки?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Как исполнить код подобный этому (внизу) к любым файлам .csv в папке /example?

То есть, хочу открыть все файлы из папки и произвести по ним различные расчёты, но так, чтобы в итоге все `print` были в одном общем выводе.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df.columns = ['one', 'two', 'tree', 'foo']
...
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

one_l = list(df['one'].values)
value = 0

for i in range(df):

    one = one_l[i]
    
    if one > 100 and value != 0:
        value = one
    
print(one)
value = 0
```

Не знаю, как применять OS, про который написали в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1185730/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-for-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%84%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d0%ba-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc-csv-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8/1185897#comment2064993_1185730), но если пойти путем ниже, то работать не будет:

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

p = Path(r"/data/")

for f in p.glob("*.csv"):
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    df.columns = ['one', 'two', 'tree', 'foo']
```

Comment: Лично я ничего не понял. Ни что именно вы хотите посчитать для датафрейма, ни что вы хотите получить на выходе для всех файлов. Приведите примеры имеющегося сейчас и желаемого вывода, например.

Comment: Ну, сделайте из кода функцию, которая принимает имя файла. Перебирайте файлы каталога (например, через os.walk) в цикле и вызывайте эту функцию.

Comment: Вот первая ссылка из гугл поиска [Функция os.walk()](https://pythoner.name/walk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

def fun(filename):
    # filename = str(filename)  # если не поддерживается работа с объектами `pathlib`
    # код который обрабытывает один CSV файл

_ = [fun(f) for f in Path("/path/to/example").glob("*.csv")]
```

Comment: @Nikolay_Smirnov, в Python принято называть переменные, которые мы не собираемся использовать называть знаком подчеркивания. Т.е. это обычная переменная

Comment: @Nikolay_Smirnov, укажите в вопросе небольшой пример данных для двух+ файлов и тот  результат, который вы хотите получить. PS я пока плохо читаю мысли, но я работаю в этом направлении)